# NPM install crashes with 'connection refused'

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to use `npm` to install a package. However, `npm` crashes every single time whenever I try to install anything.

**Here's the error I keep on receiving:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'npm' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.9.0
4 verbose npm-session 06d9b7b22d5c60b9
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 73386ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\trinch\repos\gekko
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm"
15 verbose node v10.9.0
16 verbose npm  v6.2.0
17 error code ECONNREFUSED
18 error errno ECONNREFUSED
19 error FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
19 error     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
19 error     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
19 error     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
19 error     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
19 error     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
19 error     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
19 error     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
19 error  { FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
19 error     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
19 error     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
19 error     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
19 error     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
19 error     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
19 error     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
19 error     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
19 error   message:
19 error    'request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
19 error   type: 'system',
19 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
19 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
19 error   stack:
19 error    'FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-fetch-npm\\src\\index.js:68:14)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)' }
20 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
20 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**My settings:**
I am not behind a proxy and my `npm` config list looks like this:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = "@xtrinch"
user-agent = "npm/6.2.0 node/v10.9.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\trinch\.npmrc
msvs_version = "2017"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\trinch\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\trinch\repos\gekko
; HOME = C:\Users\trinch
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Package versions:

```
PS C:\Users\trinch> node -v
v10.9.0
PS C:\Users\trinch> npm -v
6.2.0
```

Do you know what can I do about this? I have no idea so far on how to solve this problem. Looking forward any help I can get on this issue!

In case you do need more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have somehow accidentally set `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and proxy user environment variables to `http://@trinch` which resolved to localhost. Removing them did the trick.